# Installing WINE 1.4 Errors on Precise 12.04

Tags: wine

This message is consistently received when installing WINE1.4, which fails to install properly

update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic-pae
Fatal: No images have been defined.
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Why are you installing WINE 1.4? Install Wine 1.5 its the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to a conflict with the lilo package, which appears to be installed on your system. The default boot loader for Ubuntu is Grub2, you probably don't need lilo.

Try `sudo apt-get remove lilo`. Then try, eg. `sudo dpkg --configure initramfs-tools`. The error messages should go away and you should be able to install wine (version 1.4 or 1.5 indeed).

Comment: Jasmines, that led to the solution anyway. Removed lilo, but could not configure initramfs-tools as they were already configured. Uninstalled Wine1.4 in terminal (sudo apt-get autoremove wine1.4) which removed Wine1.4 and installed Wine1.5x, which installed without errors. Thanks for your input!